# Deleting last line from file in C - creates empty line

Tags: c

I want to delete a given line in a text file so I use a temporary file writing all lines except the one we want to delete.

Everything is okay except for the last line of the file: when I want to delete the last line the result is an empty line in place of the deleted line but it should have nothing and not an empty line

```
char line[255];
unsigned int countline=0;
unsigned int linetodelete;//fixed by the user

FILE *file=fopen(filename,"r");
FILE *filetemp=fopen("__tempfile__","w");

while(fgets(line,255,file)!=NULL){
    if(countline!=linetodelete)
        fputs(line,filetemp);
    countline++;
}

fclose(file);
fclose(filetemp);

file=fopen(filename,"w");
filetemp=fopen("__tempfile__","r");

while(fgets(line,255,filetemp)!=NULL)
    fputs(line,file);

fclose(file);
fclose(filetemp);
remove("__tempfile__");
```

file example: (I add line number to illustrate what we can see in the file)

```
000 line0
001 line1
002 line2
```

result when asking to delete line 1 (001):

```
000 line0
001 line2
```

result when asking to delete line 2 (002):

```
000 line0
001 line1
002
```

see the blank line ? Why is this ? How to deal with it ? Thanks

EDIT: precisions

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void deleteline(const char *filename,unsigned int linetodelete){
    FILE *file=fopen(filename,"r");
    FILE *filetemp=fopen("__tempfile__","w");

    char line[255];
    unsigned int countline=0;

    while(fgets(line,255,file)!=NULL){
        if(countline!=linetodelete)
            fputs(line,filetemp);
        countline++;
    }
    fclose(file);
    fclose(filetemp);
    rename("__tempfile__",filename);
}
void print(const char *filename){
    FILE *file=fopen(filename,"r");

    char line[255];
    unsigned int countline=0;

    while(fgets(line,255,file)!=NULL){
        printf("%03d ", countline);
        printf("%s",line);
        countline++;
    }
    printf("\r\n");
    fclose(file);
}
int main(){
    printf("before\n");
    print("test.txt");
    deleteline("test.txt",2);
    printf("after\n");
    print("test.txt");
}
```

before:

```
cat -n test.txt 
1   line0 
2   line1 
3   line2
```

after:

```
cat -n test.txt
1   line0 
2   line1
```

and here is what I get in my file editor:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3KPN.jpg

in term:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HXxEY.jpg

Comment: Not sure what you're problem is, but have you considered simply renaming your temp file to your original file, rather than copying the contents?

Comment: Nice idea to avoid another loop, but there's still the blank line at the end of the file, if I get 3 lines and I ask my prog to delete the last line, there's still 3 lines, the difference is that the 3rd line will be blank and not deleted.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem with the code shown. Can you please show the exact resulting files in both cases by showing the output of `cat -n <filename>` (I'm assuming you are on Linux)?

Comment: before:
 cat -n test.txt
     1 line0
     2 line1
     3 line2

after:
cat -n test.txt
     1 line0
     2 line1

and here is what I get in my file editor: http://imgur.com/8Wbiwk2
(I made a print function in C and I see this 3rd blank line too)

Comment: Are you sure the problem doesn’t come from your file editor? For instance, in many cases emacs will automatically add an empty new line at the end of a file if there is not already one.

Comment: There isn't this blank line before runing the code, it's poping after execution and when I print the file with my print function I see this blank line too but without the line number...

Comment: Even the result of cat show that there is a new line: http://imgur.com/WGNSmgf

Comment: See my answer, @Vertus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this turnaround :

```
if(countline!=linetodelete){
    char *p = line;
    p[strlen(p)-1] = 0;
    if(countline == 0){
        fprintf(filetemp, "%s", p);
    }
    else{
        fprintf(filetemp, "\n%s", p);
    }
}
```

This way, you can avoid a blank line at the end of the file.

Answer (score 0):

All lines but the last of your file have a `'\n'` character on it. So the **second to last** line has it, of course.

When you delete the last line, obviously the output won't be similar as before, because the last line, which didn't have a `'\n'` before, now has it (it comes from what was previously the second to last line).

I've written this and I don't like it very much, but if it helps to give you an idea of a better solution...

```
void deleteline(const char *filename,unsigned int linetodelete){
    FILE *file=fopen(filename,"r");
    FILE *filetemp=fopen("__tempfile__","w");

    char line[255];
    unsigned int last = 0;

    while(fgets(line,255,file)!=NULL){
        last++;
    }
    last--;

    rewind(file);

    unsigned int countline=0;

    while(fgets(line,255,file)!=NULL) {
       if (linetodelete != last) {
            if (countline != linetodelete)
            fputs(line, filetemp);
        }
        else {
            if (countline == linetodelete - 1) 
                line[strlen(line) - 1] = '\0';

            if (countline != linetodelete)
                fputs(line, filetemp);
        }
        countline++;
    }

    fclose(file);
    fclose(filetemp);
    rename("__tempfile__",filename);
}
```